# writing a string to file as a sequence of bytes

Tags: c++, string, winapi, std

I want to write a wide string to a file as a sequence of bytes. I tried two ways, the first way:

```
std::wstring str = L"This is a test";

LPBYTE pBuf = (LPBYTE)str.c_str();

FILE* hFile = _wfopen( L"c:\\temp.txt", L"w" );

for( int i = 0; i<(str.length()*sizeof(wchar_t)); ++i)
    fwprintf( hFile, L"%02X", pBuf[i] ); 

fclose(hFile);
```

The second way:

```
std::wstring str = L"This is a test";

LPBYTE pBuf = (LPBYTE)str.c_str();

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( L"c:\\temp.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );

DWORD dwRet;
WriteFile( hFile, pBuf, str.length()*sizeof(wchar_t), &dwRet, NULL );

CloseHandle(hFile);
```

When I open the result file, in the first case the contents of the file are:
54006800690073002000690073002000610020007400650073007400

In the second case, the contents of the file are:
This is a test

Why the first way doesn't work as expected? it looks like both ways are equal.

Comment: The *%02X* format requests that a number (your `pBuf[i]`) be outputted in a human-readable hexadecimal format, so for example the number 255 would result in the characters 'F' and 'F'.  That's vastly different to output of one character with value 255/0xFF (which you'd get from the "%c" format).

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, you used fwprintf to format the bytes as 2-digit hex strings so that is why you see hex in that file.

I suspect you should spend some time researching the ASCII code and UTF-16LE and looking at text using a hex editor.

Every file is just a sequence of bytes so your question is not well defined and makes me think you have some fundamental misunderstanding about bytes and encodings but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: so how WriteFile formats the bytes? how do you format the bytes using fprintf in the same way that WriteFile does?

Comment: WriteFile does not format anything.  It takes the bytes you give it and it writes them to the file.  The input to WriteFile is a series of bytes and the things it writes to the file are bytes and I don't think it changes them.  If you really want to use fprintf, I think you should use `%s` and pass it a pointer to your string's bytes.  However, since you have working code I don't know why you want to use fprintf.  Perhaps ask a new question on this site where you explain your ultimate goal.

Comment: `fwprintf` probably calls `WriteFile` or something similar after it is done applying the format.  `WriteFile` is lower-level.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to write out the in-memory representation of the string:

```
#include <fstream>

int main (int argc,char *argv[]) {
  std::wstring str = L"This is a test";

  std::ofstream fout(R"(c:\temp.txt)");
  fout.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);

  fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str.data()), sizeof(wchar_t) * str.size());
}
```

We use `ofstream` because this is C++ and it's better to use RAII types instead of having to manually call `fclose` or `CloseHandle`. We use a raw string for the filename so we don't have to deal with escaping the backslash. (On platforms that use a sensible path separator ; )  the raw string here is unnecessary.) We also turn on exceptions so that we don't have to explicitly check for errors.

Then we write out the bytes using the `write` member function. Note that the `codecvt` facet is still applied to the data written using this method. This is the reason we're using `ofstream` instead of `wofstream`; The default facet for ofstream does nothing, but the default facet for `wofstream` would convert the wchar_t to char using the default locale.

---

If you simply want to write UTF-16 data out then there are better ways than trying to write the raw bytes of a `wchar_t` string. (`wchar_t` isn't necessarily UTF-16. Some platforms just happen to use UTF-16.)

One way is to use a the `codecvt_utf16` facet:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::wstring str = L"This is a test";

  std::wofstream fout(R"(C:\temp.txt)");
  fout.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
  fout.imbue(std::locale(std::locale("C"), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>));

  fout << str;
}
```

Here we write a `wchar_t` string normally, but we've imbued the wstream with `codecvt_utf16`, so that the the `wchar_t` is converted to UTF-16. If you want little endian UTF-16, or you want to include U+FEFF at the beginning of the file (these are frequently done on Windows) then there are flags to enable that: `std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10FFFF, std::codecvt_mode::generate_header | std::codecvt_mode::little_endian>`. (also note that `codecvt_utf16` will treat `wchar_t` as UCS-2 or UCS-4, never UTF-16. The upshot is that this only handles the BMP on Windows)

---

Another option is to use normal streams and the `wstring_convert` facility:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::wstring str = L"This is a test";

  std::ofstream fout(R"(C:\temp.txt)");
  fout.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);

  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;    
  fout << convert.to_bytes(str);
}
```

This is probably the option I would choose, since it allows one to almost completely avoid `wchar_t`.